# Autoplay audio in Wordpress not working even after a click or interaction on the popup

Tags: wordpress, divi

I am creating a web page by using Wordpress & Divi Builder which a background music will automatically play after the page load. According to the Chrome's autoplay policy, autoplay with sound is allowed if the user has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).

So, I create a popup so user must click the button to close the popup. However, the music doesn't play.

The web page is here: https://www.invitegrafy.com/general-template-1-minimalist/

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.